# c++11 combining std::tuple and std::tie for efficient ordering

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl, boost-tuples

I am fairly new to std::tuple and std::tie.  I need a way to efficiently order structs according to a left to right ordering of comparisons.  For this reason, I chose to use the [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) and [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) types for custom ordering a StructA in the [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a882b8ae062e42ac) provided.  The tuple approach provides built in equivalence comparisons starting from left to right which is ideal for *LessThanComparable* element ordering for a std::sort with an accompanying lambda comparator (for which I show 3 examples).

The problem is that as far as I am aware, [std::make_tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) makes [inefficient copies](http://vexorian.blogspot.com/2013/07/more-about-c11-tuples-tie-and-maketuple.html) of the tuple elements, and I was wondering if there was some way to combine std::make_tuple with std::tie as I tried to do with my 3rd comparator - which failed (otherwise its output would look like the first output ordering).

In my specific example I cannot use [std::tie](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) directly as I need to use a temporary as the 1st element in my tuple.

The output is as follows

```
Order[mPath.filename(), elem1, intVal]
======================================
"/zoo/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 1
"/tmp/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 3
"/fad/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 4

Order[mPath, elem1, intVal]
======================================
"/fad/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 4
"/tmp/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 3
"/zoo/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 1

Order[mPath.filename(), elem1, intVal]
======================================
"/fad/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 4
"/tmp/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 3
"/zoo/dir1/filename.txt" - nameA1 - 1
```

I was expecting that the 3rd set of outputs would be identical to the first or alternatively if someone could tell me how to correctly mix inefficient std::tuples with efficient std::ties

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

struct StructA {
    boost::filesystem::path mPath;
    std::string elem1;
    int intVal;
};

template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& 
operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os, StructA const& sa) {
    return os << sa.mPath << " - " << sa.elem1 << " - " << sa.intVal << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::vector<StructA> aStructs = {
        {"/zoo/dir1/filename.txt", "nameA1", 1}, 
        {"/fad/dir1/filename.txt", "nameA1", 4}, 
        {"/tmp/dir1/filename.txt", "nameA1", 3}
    };    

    std::cout << "Order[mPath.filename(), elem1, intVal]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "======================================" << std::endl;
    std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        [](const StructA& lhs, const StructA& rhs){
            return std::make_tuple(lhs.mPath.filename(), lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < 
                std::make_tuple(rhs.mPath.filename(), rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);
        });

    // print reordered structs
    std::copy(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<StructA>(std::cout, ""));        

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Order[mPath, elem1, intVal]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "======================================" << std::endl;
    std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        [](const StructA& lhs, const StructA& rhs){
            return std::tie(lhs.mPath, lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < 
                std::tie(rhs.mPath, rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);
        });

    // print reordered structs
    std::copy(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<StructA>(std::cout, ""));

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Order[mPath.filename(), elem1, intVal]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "======================================" << std::endl;
    std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        [](const StructA& lhs, const StructA& rhs){
            // attempt at efficiency - but not quite right
            return lhs.mPath.filename() < rhs.mPath.filename() && 
                std::tie(lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < std::tie(rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);
        });

    // print reordered structs
    std::copy(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<StructA>(std::cout, ""));
}
```

Comment: What about [`forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)?

Comment: You can still use `std::tie` with some `as_lvalue`, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23566857/420683

Comment: Assign the return values from `filename()` calls to local variables, and then use `std::tie`. Not a very scalable solution, but not bad when you're only dealing with 2 such variables.

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure how to use forward_as_tuple - but I did find a way to make my 3rd lambda to match the output of the first comparison - effectively making just 1 of the elements in the tuple inefficient.  What I failed to do in my 3rd lambda was to compare correctly using (3) in the following http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Comment: @Praetorian, std::tie takes lvalue references - that will not work, that is why my 3rd lambda used  
lhs.mPath.filename() < rhs.mPath.filename() && std::tie(lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < std::tie(rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);  See my comment above though - this was flawed

Comment: @johnco3 What I meant was `auto f1 = lhs.mPath.filename(); auto f2 = rhs.mPath.filename(); return std::tie(f1, lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < std::tie(f2, rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);`

Comment: @Praetorian - Fantastic - that was the answer I was searching for!! Nice job!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered that the problem with the 3rd lambda was that I was not correctly comparing the elements correctly for equivalence and lexicographical comparison.  The correct approach is outlined in bullet 3) for [tuple comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) where it indicates that I should use the following approach.

> 3) (bool)(std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs)) ||
>   (!(bool)(std::get<0>(rhs) < std::get<0>(lhs)) && lhstail < rhstail),
>   where lhstail is lhs without its first element, and rhstail is rhs
>   without its first element. For two empty tuples, returns false.

The fixed up lambda comparator for sorting firsty sorts according to the filename() temporary and then uses the efficient std::tie for the other elements in the tuple

```
std::cout << "Order[mPath.filename(), elem1, intVal]" << std::endl;
std::cout << "======================================" << std::endl;
std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
    [](const StructA& lhs, const StructA& rhs){
        // attempt at efficiency - but not quite right
        // AHA, I think I figured it out - see tuple operator_cmp
        // return value documentation which states 
        // (bool)(std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs)) || 
        // (!(bool)(std::get<0>(rhs) < std::get<0>(lhs)) && 
        // lhstail < rhstail), where lhstail is lhs without 
        // its first element, and rhstail is rhs without its 
        // first element. For two empty tuples, returns false.
        // --------------------------------------------------------
        // edit thanks to @Praetorian for suggesting the following:
        // --------------------------------------------------------
        auto f1 = lhs.mPath.filename(); auto f2 = rhs.mPath.filename();            
        return std::tie(f1, lhs.elem1, lhs.intVal) < std::tie(f2, rhs.elem1, rhs.intVal);
    });
```

Doing so made the first set of results identical to the 3rd - not incredibly efficient for the filename() temporary but at least I don't take the std::make_tuple hit for all elements in my struct.  The updated live example is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/023f438b83e9adf3)

Comment: Did you actually profile an optimized build? I would think a good compiler should be able to optimize away the copies in the make_tuple() version and according to the comments on this answer that appears to be the case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6219150/139091

Comment: No I never got a chance to test the performance difference, One the links in the original question indicated that an extra copy would be needed to put make_tuple, that being said the implementation I see in Visual C++ 2013 is as follows so it would appear to perfect forward temporaries
    // FUNCTION make_tuple
template<class... _Types> inline
 tuple<typename _Unrefwrap<_Types>::type...>
  make_tuple(_Types&&... _Args)
 { // make tuple from elements
 typedef tuple<typename _Unrefwrap<_Types>::type...> _Ttype;
 return (_Ttype(_STD forward<_Types>(_Args)...));
 }

Answer (score 3):

```
std::tuple<std::string, std::string const&, int>
sort_helper(StructA const& s){
  return{ s.mPath.filename(), s.elem1, s.intVal };
}
```

then:

```
std::sort(aStructs.begin(), aStructs.end(),
  [](const StructA& lhs, const StructA& rhs){
    return sort_helper(lhs)<sort_helper(rhs);
  }
);
```

which seems much cleaner no?

At the cost of one `std::string` move, basically.